# By using DECODE function, changing date to any string?

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I have 2 tables: **SHARES** and **TRANSACTIONS**. **Shares** contains companies id, name, etc. **Transactions** contains the date of the trade, shareid. I need a select query that lists the DATE of the transaction and the COMPANYNAME, BUT if a company's share had no transaction, it still should appear in the list but at the date column it has to write 'No trade'.

Example:

**SHARES**

```
shareid companyname
0       Apple
1       Microsoft
2       Samsung
3       Nokia
```

**TRANSACTIONS:**

```
transactionid   shareid  date
0               0        2016-12-4
1               1        2015-5-3
2               2        2014-10-22
3               2        2014-11-11
```

The query I need should make the next list:

```
Apple      2016-12-4
Microsoft  2015-5-3
Samsung    2014-10-22
Samsung    2014-11-11
Nokia      No trade
```

The task says that the date format has to be YYYY-MM-DD and need to use the functions DECODE and TO_CHAR.

Comment: You can use LEFT JOIN from `shares` to `transactions` and replace the date column with 'No trade', when it is NULL. And when NOT NULL, just you the functions specified to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple outer join to me. I would use `coalesce()` instead of `decode()` however:

```
select s.companyname, 
       coalesce(to_char(t.date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'No trade')
from shares s 
   left join transactions t on s.shareid = t.shareid
order by s.companyname;
```

The outer join will return all rows from the `shares` table and a `null` value in the `transactions.date` column for those shares that did not have transaction. `to_char()` converts the date to a string and `coalesce()` will pick the first non-null value. So if `t.date` is null, it returns `'No trade'`

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thank you. However if you have some free minutes and could show me how it would look using "decode()" I would like it! But thanks anyway!

Comment: I could make it. Thank you for the full answer. I can fully understand. Thank you.

Comment: I made it like this and gives the same result: SELECT s.companyname, DECODE(t.dateprocessed, NULL, 'NEVER', TO_CHAR(t.dateprocessed, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) AS date_traded
FROM shares s 
   LEFT JOIN transactions t ON s.shareid = t.shareid
ORDER BY s.companyname;

Comment: Well, I do not test it. It is a date so either I get back a NULL then it has to write whatever I say, or by default it has to show the actual date.